# Exporting Firefox bookmarks as separate .URLs while preserving timestamps

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, export, json

I have a large number of Firefox bookmarks that I want to remove and archive as shortcut files (.URL).  But I would also like to preserve the date they were added as the files' *last modified* dates.

Firefox keeps its bookmarks with a bunch of meta-data such as *date added* and *last modified* in a single .json file.

What I need to do is:

1. Export the bookmarks from the .json file as individual .URLs
2. Extract the *dateAdded* meta-data and set that as the .URL file's last modified date

I don't expect any utility to have this function since its very specific. But I'm willing to try any combination of tools so long as it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Creating .URL files while preserving timestamp from any browser bookmarks.html

This VBA macro lets you convert a standard bookmarks.html file (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) to multiple .URL files (Internet Explorer)

As a bonus, it reads out the *create date* from your bookmarks and modifies the new .URL files to reflect that date in your Windows Explorer. It also preserves your folder and subfolder structure. Have a look at the screenshot

[image]

**Usage**

- start your desired browser and export your bookmarks as **HTML file**.
  Every major browser supports this ability.
- download & open your corresponding version

  - [create_URL_files.xls](http://ge.tt/5bXt7L72?c)
- Use that beautiful start button
- Excel asks for the path to your HTML file which you created in the first step
- all new shortcut files are stored in a new folder at the same place as your HTML file
- *file create* and *file modified* date are changed to their corresponding date when you first created the bookmark in your browser

**How it works**

- a VBA macro opens your HTML file as pure text in unicode (special characters are preserved)
- it searches line by line for "HREF=" and extracts the URL
- it does the same for the *date added* and for the used bookmark *title* in your browser
- it creates all subfolders according to your bookmarks structure
- it creates a new text file for each bookmark and saves the following data into that file

  ```
  [InternetShortcut]
  URL=http://www.someaddress.com/
  ```
- the file is saved as `<bookmarktitle>.url`
- the title is truncated to max 100 characters and all forbidden characters are removed
- it checks if a shortcut already exists and if yes, it appends the create date
- the given [UNIX date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is converted into a readable format
- the file creation and file modified timestamps are changed to the date, when you saved the bookmark in your browser

---

**Helpful links**

- Explains [syntax of internet shortcut files](http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article)
- Teached me [how to modify file timestamps](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FileTimes.htm)
- Online converter [for UNIX timestamps](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)
- Teached me [how to deal with Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261632/how-can-i-create-text-files-with-special-characters-in-their-filenames) in filenames and titles
- Showing me a trick to [get the Windows function CreateFileW working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133026/vb6-createfile-creates-file-with-garbled-name-in-current-working-directory#comment7120575_6133048)
  (that is a [windows kernel32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to create files with a unicode filename)
- Solved a [compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251111/how-to-make-vba-code-compatible-for-office-2010-64-bit-version-and-older-offic) between Office 2003 and Office 2013

Comment: Could you please [test this version](http://ge.tt/10CVnJV/v/0) and say if it pleases your needs. It creates subfolders according to their counterparts in firfox. And it also checks if the file already exists. if yes, it appends the add_date from the bookmark file.

Comment: Wow..this one really has gone above and beyond

Comment: I gave it a go and everything works, it is perfect.

Comment: Again, thank you so so much for the help, you have my deepest gratitude.

Comment: You are welcome, it was fun for me

Comment: These files are no longer available unfortunately. Would you also mind separating the VB from Excel so that it can be run from the command line for those of us sticking with LibreOffice?

Answer (score 2):

#### If you just want to create shortcut files from any browser without preserving the timestamps,  
than this is the easy way

1. Export your bookmarks as HTML file.
   Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome and Opera have this ability build in
2. Type<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites`
3. Temporary backup the whole content somewhere
4. Open Internet Explorer → File → Import & Export
   [image]
5. Select your HTML file and import them
6. Type<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites` again

Now you have all bookmarks as plain .URL files. You can move them where ever you want.
Internet Explorer doesn't store bookmarks the same way other browsers do (in a single file). He just creates .URL files for every bookmark in the favorites folder.

**Note:** Remember to delete the new IE favorites and restore them with your backup

Answer (score 2):

Here is nixda's code for 2013 that was edited to correct a couple typos and remove last modified date that was not found on the same line as the hyperlink in an exported html file from Google Chrome.

The following button click script was modified to comment out the last modified portion of code.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim shortcutfile As String
Dim myadddate As Double
forbidden = Array("\", "/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|", "&quot;", "&amp;", "&#39;")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
    myfullfilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="HTML Files, *.html")

    If myfullfilename = False Then Exit Sub
    mypath = Left$(myfullfilename, InStrRev(myfullfilename, "\")) & "InternetShortCuts" & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd hh-mm-ss")
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=myfullfilename, Origin:=-535, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, Space:=False

    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir mypath
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set mysheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    With mysheet
    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        If InStr(UCase(.Cells(i, 1)), "<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=") <> 0 Then
            folderend = InStrRev(.Cells(i, 1), "<")
            folderstart = InStrRev(.Cells(i, 1), ">", folderend)
            newfolder = Mid(.Cells(i, 1), folderstart + 1, folderend - folderstart - 1)

            For j = 0 To UBound(forbidden)
                newfolder = Replace(newfolder, forbidden(j), "")
            Next j

            mypath = mypath & "\" & newfolder

            On Error Resume Next
            MkDir mypath
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

        If InStr(UCase(.Cells(i, 1)), "</DL><P>") <> 0 Then
            mypath = Left(mypath, InStrRev(mypath, "\") - 1)
        End If

        If InStr(UCase(.Cells(i, 1)), "HREF=") <> 0 Then
            urlstart = InStr(.Cells(i, 1), "HREF=")
            urlend = InStr(.Cells(i, 1), "ADD_DATE=")
            myurl = Mid(.Cells(i, 1), urlstart + 6, urlend - urlstart - 8)

            'adddateend = InStr(.Cells(i, 1), "LAST_")
            'myadddate = Mid(.Cells(i, 1), urlend + 10, adddateend - urlend - 12)
            'myadddate = DateAdd("s", myadddate, DateSerial(1970, 1, 1))

            titleend = InStrRev(.Cells(i, 1), "<")
            titlestart = InStrRev(.Cells(i, 1), ">", titleend)
            mytitle = Mid(.Cells(i, 1), titlestart + 1, titleend - titlestart - 1)
            mytitle = Left(mytitle, 100)

            For j = 0 To UBound(forbidden)
                mytitle = Replace(mytitle, forbidden(j), "")
            Next j

            shortcutfile = mypath & "\" & Trim(mytitle) & ".url"

            With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                'If .FileExists(shortcutfile) Then shortcutfile = mypath & "\" & Trim(mytitle) & " " & Format(myadddate, "yyyy.mm.dd hh-mm-ss") & ".url"
                If .FileExists(shortcutfile) Then shortcutfile = mypath & "\" & Trim(mytitle) & " " & ".url"
                With .CreateTextFile(shortcutfile, , True)
                    .write "[InternetShortcut]" & vbNewLine
                    .write "URL=" & myurl
                    .Close
                End With
            End With

            Call Settimestamp(shortcutfile, myadddate)

        End If
    Next i

    Close
    .Parent.Close False

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The following change_timestamp module was modified to correct a typo when declaring CreateFileW function where lpFileName was declared as LongLong instead of Long under #VBA7 section and line continuation when declaring CreateFileW function under #Else section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const OPEN_EXISTING = &H3
Private Const FILE_SHARE_READ = &H1
Private Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE = &H2
Private Const GENERIC_WRITE = &H40000000

Public Type FileTime
    dwLowDateTime As Long
    dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type

Public Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LocalFileTimeToFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpLocalFileTime As FileTime, lpFileTime As FileTime) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SystemTimeToFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME, lpFileTime As FileTime) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateFileW Lib "kernel32.dll" _
        (ByVal lpFileName As Long, _
        ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal dwShareMode As Long, _
        ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, _
        ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal hTemplateFile As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetFileTimeCreate Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetFileTime" _
       (ByVal hFile As Long, _
        CreateTime As FileTime, _
        ByVal LastAccessTime As Long, _
        LastModified As FileTime) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function LocalFileTimeToFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpLocalFileTime As FileTime, lpFileTime As FileTime) As Long
    Private Declare Function SystemTimeToFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME, lpFileTime As FileTime) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CreateFileW Lib "kernel32.dll" _
        (ByVal lpFileName As Long, _
        ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal dwShareMode As Long, _
        ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, _
        ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal hTemplateFile As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function SetFileTimeCreate Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetFileTime" _
       (ByVal hFile As Long, _
        CreateTime As FileTime, _
        ByVal LastAccessTime As Long, _
        LastModified As FileTime) As Long
#End If

'=======================================================================================================================
'=======================================================================================================================
'=======================================================================================================================

Function Settimestamp(FileName, FileDateTime)

Dim FileHandle As Long
Dim Res As Long
Dim ErrNum As Long
Dim ErrText As String
Dim tFileTime As FileTime
Dim tLocalTime As FileTime
Dim tSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME

With tSystemTime
    .wYear = Year(FileDateTime)
    .wMonth = Month(FileDateTime)
    .wDay = Day(FileDateTime)
    .wDayOfWeek = Weekday(FileDateTime) - 1
    .wHour = Hour(FileDateTime)
    .wMinute = Minute(FileDateTime)
    .wSecond = Second(FileDateTime)
End With

Res = SystemTimeToFileTime(lpSystemTime:=tSystemTime, lpFileTime:=tLocalTime)
Res = LocalFileTimeToFileTime(lpLocalFileTime:=tLocalTime, lpFileTime:=tFileTime)

FileHandle = CreateFileW(lpFileName:=StrPtr(FileName), _
                        dwDesiredAccess:=GENERIC_WRITE, _
                        dwShareMode:=FILE_SHARE_READ Or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, _
                        lpSecurityAttributes:=ByVal 0&, _
                        dwCreationDisposition:=OPEN_EXISTING, _
                        dwFlagsAndAttributes:=0, _
                        hTemplateFile:=0)

Res = SetFileTimeCreate( _
            hFile:=FileHandle, _
            CreateTime:=tFileTime, _
            LastAccessTime:=0&, _
            LastModified:=tFileTime)

CloseHandle FileHandle

End Function
```