# How to download a link in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, browser, links

I want to have a copy on my computer of a html link, so that if I click on it, the link is opened in browser.
It's the equivalent of a bookmark, except that I saved it in a Windows folder, not on browser.

Comment: just pull the Icon from adressbar to the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @bummi already mentioned. Just drag&drop the link from any browser to your desktop.

[image]

---

#### Manual way

You can also create a new text file with notepad and save it as **myurl.url**.
The system will hide the .URL extension even if you uncheck *Hide extensions for known file types* in your folder options.

The file syntax is as follows

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://superuser.com
```

Some browsers like IE and Firefox use optional settings. They aren't mandatory.
You can see them, if you create a shortcut per drag&drop like shown above and edit the file with any editor.

```
IDList=
HotKey=
IconFile=
IconIndex=
```

Comment: If you want to create .URL files in a batch, there is [a simple trick](http://superuser.com/questions/530014/exporting-firefox-bookmarks-as-separate-urls-while-preserving-timestamps/533531#533531) using Internet Explorers ability to store its bookmarks as .URL files

Answer (score 1):

You can create a blank .html page on your desktop, with a meta redirect to the page you want to open. When you double-click the page it'll open in your default browser.

The [`file://` URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows) is what you want to use when creating the link.

Answer (score 1):

If I want to have a local copy of a page, I would try the “Save as…” option in the File menu. This will make a local copy of the HTML page along with a directory with all the related content. What I will be able to do with my local copy heavily depends on the nature of page.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to right click the link and go to "Save link as..."
[image: screen shot of right click context menu]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new shortcut, and set it to point to the URL. It will automatically be opened by the browser.

Create the shortcut by right-clicking in the folder, and selecting New -> Shortcut.

In the "New Shortcut" wizard, the system will ask you for the location of the item you want to create a shortcut for. Simply enter the URL there, like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I edited my answer with extra instructions, hope this helps.