# Exporting Firefox bookmarks as separate .URLs while preserving TAGS

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, export, tags

I realize this is a near duplicate of the question [Exporting Firefox bookmarks as separate .URLs while preserving timestamps](https://superuser.com/questions/530014/exporting-firefox-bookmarks-as-separate-urls-while-preserving-timestamps).

But I would like to save the tag metadata, if this is possible as that is how most of my bookmarks are currently sorted.

Comment: What do you mean by "save the tag metadata"? What metadata exactly? Where should it be saved? Inside the .URL files?

Comment: In the Firefox json bookmarks file is a series of metadata, time created, time last accessed amongst others. The Tag metadata is the tags you can append when saving a bookmark so rather than having a folder of Recipes say I have many bookmarks tagged 'recipe'. I would like to preserve that for sorting. I would like it saved likeany other metadata saved with eg an mp3 such as 'artist'.

Comment: You could save the json and open it as text and use [JSON 2 HTML](http://json.bloople.net/) or you could try [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) with the json file

Comment: Ups, I entirely forgot this question. Again, where should the meta tag be saved. INSIDE the .URL file? If yes, I don't see a [corresponding property](http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article) and it would not be possible to sort them in this way. Or do you mean store the tags OUTSIDE the .URL file, but in the filename itself like `C:\bookmarksfolder\www.domain.com-customtag.URL`. Or should a seperate folder be created for each tag? What if a URL has multiple tags? Should it be stored in multiple folders? How do you wanna sort them in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the simple answer is to use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). This will convert the .json backup to a table, for you. There are over [6,000 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid) related to it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's a bit beyond my ability though. I was hoping for something more along the lines of the solution here http://superuser.com/questions/530014/exporting-firefox-bookmarks-as-separate-urls-while-preserving-timestamps